# WPF DataTrigger Setter method binding

Tags: wpf, setter, datatrigger

I want to display different cell background color based on the value being changed by using Style. Here is my code. My data structure implements the INotifyPropertyChanged, whenever a property is changed, it will raise the notification (e.g. HasChange). So I assume that when HasChange is changed, it will call MyDummy converter, which always returns true, then the setting method will be called and MyConverter will work out what color to paint for the background.

When the application starts, it works fine and displays the correct color. However, when I change any cell data, MyDummy is executed, but MyConverter never gets called again. Any idea? (Please ignore the RowData.Row, they are part of DevExpress controls for datarow). Thanks.

**SOLUTION**: is to use Data instead of DataRow.Row

```
    <local:MyColorConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    <local:MyDummy x:Key="MyDummy"/>
    <Style TargetType="dxg:CellContentPresenter" x:Key="cellstyple">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.HasChange, Converter={StaticResource MyDummy}}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="RowData.Row"/>
                            <Binding Path="Column.FieldName"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Data structure I used

```
public class MyStr : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            HasChange = true;
        }
    }
    public String City { get; set; }
    private bool _hasChange;
    public bool HasChange
    {
        get
        { return _hasChange; }
        set
        {
            _hasChange = value;
            NotifyChange("HasChange");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyChange(String name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Converter is called first when it's applied and then every time any property in set binding changes. Does RowData.Row or Column.FieldName change whenever RowData.Row.HasChange's change occurs?

Comment: @Maximus the underlying data is changed when I change any cell data

Comment: looks like `Row.HasChange` does not support property change notification. You simply cannot use it in Binding.

Comment: @KingKing HasChange is the property in my data structure. I have updated the post, you can see my data structure.

Comment: I don't understand this `MyDummy is executed, but MyConverter never gets called again`, what do you mean by `MyDummy is executed`? when checking some converter (to know if it's triggered or not), normally we should set some breakpoint on the `Convert` method, is that what you mean? but then the result is as if the converter did not work?

Comment: @KingKing, I mean when I set two breakpoints, one for MyDummy and one for MyConverter. The first breakpoint is hit when I change the Name in the Grid, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: well, so looks like the `RowData.Row` or `Column.FieldName` should support property change notification. Note that they may be changed but notification about that change is another issue. Some implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be done or those properties should be `DependencyProperties`. This time I'm talking about the `RowData.Row` and `Column.FieldName` not `Row.HasChange` (I know you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for this property).